# Is there is any tool/way to find out why packet is getting dropped due to an arp cache full?

Tags: linux, kernel, performance-tuning, arp, packet

My developer hypothesis is packet is getting dropped at arp layer. We increased the default value of neigh.default.gc_thresh3 1024 --> 2048 and now everything looks good. But I want to understand is there is a way to figure it out arp packet loss.I try to search for systemtap/tools but didn't find anything. Any help is really appreciated.

```
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3=<n>
```

Comment: Did you see `neighbour: arp_cache: neighbor table overflow!` in dmesg?

Comment: Do you use Docker swarm by the way? Virtualized networking seems to be the primary area for arp cache limits to get in the way.

Comment: Nope @Gerrit, I am using Open VSwitch

Answer (score 3):

There is several articles about ARP table overflow. [This article](https://www.serveradminblog.com/2011/02/neighbour-table-overflow-sysctl-conf-tunning/) have good explanation. Also, you could check [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-nova-compute/+bug/1780348).

Both articles say that you should see error `neighbour: arp_cache: neighbor table overflow!` in your `dmesg` output, as it was mentioned in comment by **user188737**.

Comment: Thanks Alexander and user188737,but I still have the same question is dmesg is the only way or is there is any tool or kernel probe to find out the error.

Comment: @PrashantLakhera you could monitor amount of addresses in arp cache as `arp -a | wc -l` and if it near `net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh3` value, raise alert.

Comment: There is a lot of discussion about the gc_thresh values in this [nova compute bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-nova-compute/+bug/1780348). It seems you could also run into setting net.nf_conntrack_max and net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max. And also be aware that there are separate settings for ipv4 and ipv6 arp cache thresholds.